# Regex replace value with first match

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering if something like this is possible with Regex, to replace a value ('John Doe' in my example below) with the first match ('test@tester.com' in my example below):

Input:

```
Contact: <a href="mailto:test@tester.com">John Doe</a>
```

Output:

```
Contact: test@tester.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. however, your example is not clear. which part do you replace with what? As far as I can see, you just match and return some part of the string, there is no replace.

Comment: @AliFerhat I want to replace the name (John Doe) with the email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working using MatchEvaluator delegate and named captures:

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, 
    @"\<a([^>]+)href\=.?mailto\:(?<mailto>[^""'>]+).?([^>]*)\>(?<mailtext>.*?)\<\/a\>", 
    m => m.Groups["mailto"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this. The code will replace names with e-mails in all *mailto* links:

```
var html = new StringBuilder("Contact: <a href=\"mailto:test1@tester1.com\">John1 Doe1</a> <a href=\"mailto:test2@tester2.com\">John2 Doe2</a>");

var regex = new Regex(@"\<a href=\""mailto:(?<email>.*?)\""\>(?<name>.*?)\</a\>");
var matches = regex.Matches(html.ToString());

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var oldLink = match.Value;
    var email = match.Groups["email"].Value;
    var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
    var newLink = oldLink.Replace(name, email);
    html = html.Replace(oldLink, newLink);
}

Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Output:

```
Contact: <a href="mailto:test1@tester1.com">test1@tester1.com</a> <a href="mailto:test2@tester2.com">test2@tester2.com</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to "inject" the match rather than construct a new string, because the input is a large string with more text beyond what I've specified in the example.

Comment: @Nick, am I right understand that you have an HTML-page that can contain many "mailto" links and you want to replace them all?

Comment: If the HTML page is stored in a string object, then there is little chance to "inject", as the MSDN notes _Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created_. Depending on how the HTML data is retrieved, you might consider a different approach.